# git-svn branching: how to configure git config

Tags: svn, git, git-svn, branch, git-branch

a few months ago i configured a git with an svn repository. Until now i only used the svn repository to keep up-to-date with the supplied application on it. But now i also want to commit stuff back. To do this every feature i'm going to commit needs to be in a separate branch. I read about how you should create a new branch etc. But i think i mis-configured my git, i don't have any branch information etc i think i only have the trunk info. This is how my svn repository has been set up in my git config:

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = url-of-git-repository
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[svn-remote "svn"]
    url = url-of-svn-repository/trunk
    fetch = :refs/remotes/git-svn
[branch "master"]
    merge = refs/heads/master
    remote = origin
... other branch information below (these are git branches)
```

Now as you can see my svn-remote url goes directly to trunk. I read about adding this:

```
branches = branches/*:refs/remotes/*
```

but when i create a new branch then it will be adding it to trunk/branches/. When i don't add the line then it doesn't know what the destination is of the branch.

Any idea how to solve this without breaking the existing branches, code, etc.?

greets,
Daan

Answer (score 6):

I believe the branches configuration is relative to the svn-remote url.

Here's our configuration the way it was made by doing

`git svn -s url-of-svn-repository/foo`

(Inside the folder foo, we have the normal trunk/branches/tags structure)

```
[svn-remote "svn"]
        url = url-of-svn-repository
        fetch = foo/trunk:refs/remotes/trunk
        branches = foo/branches/*:refs/remotes/*
        tags = foo/tags/*:refs/remotes/tags/*
```

You could try adjusting to this structure, or do your git svn clone over again with the -s parameter. It will configure all this for you (--standard-layout).

Answer (score 0):

This was a post that helped me get git working with svn with a project that had a very unorthodox branch stucture (which is par for the course for companies using SVN for some reason I'm afraid).

http://www.dmo.ca/blog/20070608113513/

Comment: It would be in multiple ways better to have multiple svn branches handled under the same `[svn-remote xxx]` section. You do not then need to perform  `git svn fetch` for each of the branches separately. Also I think the common svn revisions are represented then as single shared commits in the mirroring git repository. You can have the `*` in the `branches` definition in any subdirectory component of the path, though you need to edit `.git/config` manually to accomplish this.